# How deep would a hole need to be before you could no longer hear the sound of a small object hitting the bottom?

Tags: kinematics, acoustics, free-fall

Assuming there are no obstructions, background noises, and the bottom of the pit is just flat concrete, if the average person were to drop something like a padlock (very specific, I know) into the hole, around what depth would they no longer be able to hear the sound of it hitting the bottom?

This is for a story I'm working on.

Comment: It would depend on the lowest pressure level the human eye could detect, how hard the impact at the bottom is, how the sidewalls of the material the hole is made of absorb air vibrations, and the width of the hole which determines how much the vibration spread out over as well as the amount of sidewall area present.

Comment: *This is for a story I'm working on.* Probably a better fit for [worldbuilding.se].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Summary:** Very deep - on the order of 1-10 kilometers.

**Analysis:**

Lets make some assumptions.  First, we are dealing with air at standard temperature, pressure, etc.  Second, lets assume that the walls of the pit are smooth, parallel, and acoustically hard so we don't have to worry about funky reflections.  Third, assume that the strike leads to an impulse with roughly equal energy from 1 kHz to 10 kHz with an amplitude of 80 dB.  I am really just guessing about the source, but this estimate should put you in the ballpark.  The high frequencies are attenuated faster than the lower frequencies, so we will focus on the 1 kHz component, which is also where the ear reaches its peak sensitivity.  At this frequency atmosphere attenuation leads to a loss of about 6 dB per kilometer.  Finally, without background noise and the listener actively searching for a signal we will assume the received signal must be below 10 dB to be inaudible.  Thus, for these assumptions the pit would need to be $(80-10)/6\approx12$ km deep.  Over this distance, the assumption of the uniform atmosphere breaks down a bit, but not significantly.  If we assume the peak frequency was actually a little higher, say 4 kHz, the absorption  is roughly 20 dB per kilometer, and the depth is about 3.5 km.

I don't know what order of magnitude you were hoping for, but these depths seem extremely large to me.  There are a variety of reasons for the large values.  For example, the still air with no background noise permits one to hear very quiet sounds.  Also, all of the sound is being directed in one direction (up the pit) rather than in all directions as in the case of open air propagation.  Another is the fact that we are neglecting any sort of phenomena that would distort the signal into something unrecognizable (like atmospheric turbulence).  If you want small depths, just allow for some moderate background noise, such as wind or motor noise, up to a level of roughly 50 dB (still pretty quiet for our modern world), and then the 4 kHz depth becomes 1.5 km.  Then you could assume the sound from the strike was actually lower for some reason (e.g., it slowed down or it was actually not very dense), and the source was actually only 70 dB, and now the pit is only 1 km.

Comment: Nice answer. Just a quick short correction. The listening mechanism peaks at around 3 KHz to 5 KHz (somewhere closer to 3 KHz than the other extreme, most of the time). Other than that, one could possibly consider the fact that there's gonna be reflections off the walls, which will increase somehow the final level (the attenuation numbers you provided I assume are for free field propagation).

Comment: @ZaellixA The attenuation numbers I used are indeed for free field propagation.  I had forgotten that cross-modes are not necessarily evanescent in this case, but they will be attenuated faster than the plane wave mode.  Thus, by the top of the pit I think the plane wave mode will dominate the other modes by a lot, so using the free-space values is probably acceptable (assuming rigid, smooth, and parallel walls).

Comment: Agreed. I just wanted to add some emphasis on the fact that even those high numbers of distance (hole length) may already be small and even greater a length would be required in real life.